# Convert Null Terminated Byte strings to Raw String Literal

Tags: c++

Disclaimer: I have only recently started with C++ and I am still trying to understand its basic concepts.

Say, for example, we have to following statement:

```
std::cout << "^\\s+Encryption key:(\\w+)"        << '\n' << 
             "^\\s+Quality=(\\d+)"               << '\n' <<
             "^\\s+E?SSID:\"([[:print:]]+)\""    << '\n' <<
             "^\\s+ssid=\"([[:print:]]+)\""      << '\n';
```

How can one convert this to a single raw string literal? I tried to read as much as possible about this subject, but can't seem to figure out how to do this. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I understand `)"` can not be used directly in a RSL.

Comment: There: `"^\\s+Encryption key:(\\w+)\n^\\s+Quality=(\\d+)\n^\\s+E?SSID:\"([[:print:]]+)\"\n^\\s+ssid=\"([[:print:]]+)\"\n"`. It is a single raw string literal.

Comment: A raw string literal is something different. http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#def:raw_string_literal

Comment: @Swordfish I saw your comment and removed my answer as it was wrong. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `(` and `)` in raw string literals. You just have to specify the start/stop delimiter sequence so that you don't get a delimiter sequence preceded by a `)` in the string. The null character is always appended. See [cppreference string literal documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for details.

In the following example, `###` is the delimiter, but you can select whatever you want (except these characters are not allowed: `() \`, and the length must be 16 characters or fewer). Just select something that won't cause you to accidentally terminate the literal prematurely.

With `###` as the delimiter, the compiler will continue consuming text as part of the raw string literal until it comes to the combination `)###"`, so technically you could have `)###` in your text without terminating the raw string literal, but I think it's best to play it safe -- you could inadvertently terminate the literal prematurely if there happens to be a `"` immediately after that sequence. I'd also avoid the situation where you have the delimiter followed by  `(` in the body of the literal -- `###(` in this example. It's allowed, but could confuse people reading the program.

So this could be

```
std::cout << R"###(^\s+Encryption key:(\w+)
^\s+Quality=(\d+)
^\s+E?SSID:"([[:print:]]+)"
^\s+ssid="([[:print:]]+)"
)###"  ;
```

In a raw string literal, you don't escape characters, so `\\` becomes `\` and `\"` becomes `"` in your example, and `\n` become actual newlines.